# Eclipse : content assist in jsp and include from jar

Tags: eclipse, jsp-tags

is it possible for eclipse to scan a file that is in a jar file ?

For example :

a.jar contains a file include.tagf

```
 META-INF
     resources
         tagsdef
```

include.tagf contains several taglib directives (custom tags, spring, jstl, c, etc)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="mytags" tagdir="/mytagjar/mytags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
```

Now, in a project having a.jar as a maven dependency, if I work on some jsp that have a directive to include include.tagf :

```
<%@ include file="/tagsdef/include.tagf" %>
```

I would like content assist for the taglib defined in include.tagf, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, probably an Eclipse bug... The only thing I've gotten to work is `*.tld` files in separate JAR files. Please update this question if you find an answer, thanks!

Comment: This answer explains how it should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18804849/3375325
So you should reference it indirectly with a `tagdir` instead of a `file` attribute.

Comment: I simplified the structure of a.jar, but in fact custom tags are in META-INF/tags, with a tld file in META-INF. So in fact the taglib directive uses the uri attribute. Anyway, if I put the taglib directive in the the jsp, it works so the tag jar works as it should. But including an intermediate file doesn't.

Comment: Does your `<%@ taglib prefix="mytags" tagdir="/mytagjar/mytags"%>` work if the directory is in your `a.jar`? The only thing which works for me is `<%@ taglib uri="..." prefix="..."`. All `<%@ include file="..."` fail for me, too.

Comment: if the include file and the tags are in /META-INF/resources of a.jar, you can work out something that will work at runtime without the tlds and with tagdir instead or uri. It won't solve the content assist problem though. For the moment I stick with standard taglib jar (tld and tags in META-INF), and the include file in the project somewhere in WEB-INF.